# Generate arrays that contain every combination of elements from an array

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have an array with approximately 1000 elements what I want to do is generate arrays of size 100 from that array that contain every combination of elements. For example let's say I have this array:

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J]
```

Splitting it into arrays with size two I want arrays that look like this:

```
[A,B]
[A,C]
[A,D]
[A,E]
[A,F]
[A,G]
[A,H]
[A,I]
[A,J]
[B,C]
...etc...
```

I am pretty confused on how to do this any advice would help,

Thanks

Comment: Do you care which combinations you get? There are an enormous number of combinations of 100 elements that can be made from 1000 values. To be precise, there are [more than 6.385e139](https://www.google.com/search?q=1000+choose+100) different combinations, so you're not going to be able to use them all in any practical way. Many algorithms will generate those combinations for you, but they'll often be in lexicographical order (like the order you show in your 2-combination example). That may not be desirable if you're going to be able to work with a small fraction of them.

Comment: A list of 1000 elements taken 100 at a time is going to be a very large list!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [combinations](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html) module:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations('ABCD', 2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

The first argument is the input list, the second argument is the length of the generated subsequences.

Comment: Importantly, `itertools.combinations` returns an generator, not a list. That means it doesn't need to use a lot of memory, since it creates each combination as you iterate to it, rather than up front. This matters when the number of combinations is big (though you'll have issues with running time too, if you really do want all combinations of 100 elements from a set of 1000).

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in array:
    for b in array:
        print [a, b]
```

Comment: This isn't what the questioner was asking for, since you'll print out `[A,A]` and both `[A,B]` and `[B,A]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
lst = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J]
newlst = []
for i in lst:
    for y in lst:
        newlst.append([i,y])
print newlst
```